# How can I check if a string contains only operator

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a string that contains "=" and no alphabet.

```
q = "="
```

I understand `isalpha()` is used to check if a string contains only alphabet but I'd like to know how to check if a string contains only operators. I don't want to check `q == "="` because sometimes there are white spaces stored with the operator saved in q.

Comment: use `q.strip() == "="`

Comment: An alphabet is a *collection* of characters. A member of an alphabet is an alphabetic character.

Comment: @chepner edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove whitespaces and use a regex to match only '=' (once or more). Sample:

```
import re

q = ' == '

if (re.match("^\\=+$", q.replace(' ', ''))):
    print('Match')
```